# How do I set objects in XML to resize with the screen?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have set up my screen in XML how I want but I want it to scale the view with increasing screen sizes so it all looks the same. How do I set that?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/StartScreen"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_plate"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_plate" />
```

Above is an example of what my object properties look like and I thought (still new to XML) that if I set the height and width as dp values then they get scaled up with the screen size, as opposed to px which don't.

Am I misunderstanding something or have I just missed an attribute?

Thanks

Comment: use dimensions for scale  ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi..etc and the image needs a resource for every display dimension your application will support.

Answer (score 0):

In your case since you are specifying a fixed layout height and width it won't change as you wish. Instead use wrap_content or match_parent according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an image with perfect height and width then use the following procedure :

1.first get the actual height and width of your image from image properties.(suppose 520 X 880)

2.then check your mobile screen height and width (we basically used 320 X 480)

3.then what will be the actual height and width of our image ?

image dimension = required screen dimension

520/880 = 480/320

if you want actual height then 
  x = (320*520)/880

for width put 320 as y.